# Dynamically created button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm try to do a bit of WPF, only really done windows forms until now and not a lot of that...

All I'm trying to do is to dynamically within code (not xaml) set a button to show an image and set the size of the button to auto size to the image.

The code below loads the image but it goes when the mouse is over the button and the button doesn't auto size to the image.

`tbButtonPicture` contains a local path on the PC to a bitmap e.g. `C:\temp\my Artwork\test1.bmp`

This what I have thus far which sits inside a loop:

```
Console.WriteLine(tbButtonPicture);
System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
//newBtn.Content = i.ToString();
newBtn.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), tbButtonPicture)));
newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
sp.Children.Add(newBtn);

i++;
```

Comment: sorry Nemesv, I have updated it with a question!

Comment: Why just not add some `ItemsControl` derived class and bind it to container of data?

Comment: Hi Serge, thank you for your suggestion but I don't have a clue how I would do this! I will google ItemsControl. it was easier when you just set a property in winforms :( I think even this simple task is giving me a lot of new things to lean...

Comment: Read [the overviews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx), especially the ones on [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your image in an Image control and set this as the button content and you should have your desired effect.

```
  System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
  Image imageControl = new Image();
  imageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), tbButtonPicture));
  newBtn.Content = imageControl;
  newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
  sp.Children.Add(newBtn);

  i++;
```

But I totally agree with above comments: 
try to solve your issues in xaml its much more easier. Read the suggested resources, they are really helpful.